# Write a Boolean expression that evaluates to true and only if x and y are both not in the range 0 to 100 inclusive, and y is greater than x

Tags: python, boolean, expression

This is what I have done.

(((((x<0) and (x>100)) and (y<0) and (y>100))) and (y>x))

Comment: _' I just want to make sure if it is write.'_ - you should do what everyone else does, and __test it__.

Comment: How can `x` be less than `0` yet greater than `100`?

Comment: How can `(x<0) and (x>100)` be true?

Comment: Because it wants it not in the range of 0 to 100

Comment: @ibrahimalhumaidi: The correct way to express that would be (x<0) or (x>100).

Answer (score 4):

Your expression is wrong. How can any value be <0 and >100 at the same time? It will always be false.

One possible correct expression that uses the power of Python is

```
y>x and not 0<=x<=100 and not 0<=y<=100
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/gZWpI1)

Comment: I'd check `y>x` first because it's the simplest and short-circuiting would eliminate the evaluation of the other two more complicated sub-expressions.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the recommendation I edited my answer. That happens when you implement the specification from top to bottom without thinking too much :)